# AngularJS - reloading div without reloading page

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, page-refresh, servicenow

Our team is developing a questionnaire widget in ServiceNow and would like a specific div to appear once a user completes a questionnaire without reloading the entire page.

The entire code is rather lengthy, but this is the specific div that should appear once the questionnaire is submitted:

```
<div align="center" ng-if="taskCompleted == true" class="infoDiv">
          <div class="mainTitle first">Task Complete!</div>
          <div class="subTitle second" style="max-width: 600px;">This task was completed on: {{params.taskCompleteDate.split(" ")[0]}}</div>
          <!-- Add section to indicate they can review their answers here-->
          <div align="left" style="margin-top: 40px; font-size: 16px; color: #979797;">
            Review Completed Questionnaire Below:
          </div>
          <div style="height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll; margin-top: 10px; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; border-radius: 2px;" align="left">
            <div ng-repeat="item in completedQuest track by $index" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 15px; min-width: 400px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee; margin-bottom: 10px;" ng-if="item.ans">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td rowspan="2" style="color: #979797; padding-right: 15px; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="editQuestionFnct(item.quest_id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit Answer" style="padding-right: 5px;"></span></td>
                  <!--<td rowspan="2" style="color: #979797; padding-right: 15px; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="showPrerenderedDialog2('#editQuestion', item.quest_id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit Answer" style="padding-right: 5px;"></span></td>-->
                  <td style="color: #336796;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" title="Question mark icon" style="padding-right: 5px;"></span></td>
                  <td><span style="color: #717171;">{{item.quest}}</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top: 10px; color: green;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" title="Check mark icon" style="padding-right: 5px;"></span></td>
                  <!--<td style="padding-top: 10px;"><span style="color: black;">{{item.answer}}</span></td>-->
                  <td style="padding-top: 10px;"><span style="color: black;">{{item.ans}}</span></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Right now, when a user completes the questionnaire, they will see a generic Thank You message:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 25px;" ng-if="params.finishQs" ng-class="params.questClass">
          Thank you for your responses!
</div>
```

And would need to ctrl-r refresh the page in order to see the above div that allows them to edit answers.  Is there any way for that div to show up without reloading the entire page?  I'm pretty new to angularjs so any advice/suggestions is helpful, thanks!

Comment: Add `ng-if="params.finishQs"` to the div just like you have in your "Thank you" message?

Comment: Setting `$scope.taskCompleted=true` should be sufficient to make the `div` appear, provided the `div` is inside the relevant scope.

Answer (score 2):

After complete form just set

```
$scope.taskCompleted = true;
```

Or you can do it in html

```
<button ng-click="taskCompleted=true;">Complete</button>
```

P.S. My recommendation not to use expressions {{}}. Instead use ng-bind for better performance.